# Spark Streaming how to guarantee order of multiple foreachRDD

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I would like to perform a sequence of actions on a DStream. Action N+1 must be executed after action N. What is the difference between these implementations?

```
val myDStream = ???

//version 1
myDStream.foreachRDD(rdd => action 1)
myDStream.foreachRDD(rdd => action 2)
myDStream.foreachRDD(rdd => action 3)

//version 2
myDStream.foreachRDD{rdd => 
  action 1
  action 2
  action 3
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we assume that each `action` operates on the complete RDD, such as `action(rdd)`, then the two expressions should be equivalent in the order of the results.

At execution level, the top version will generate three spark jobs, while the bottom version will generate only one.

Comment: Let's assume each action (which indeed operates on the entire rdd). Is very resource intensive. Which version is better (split into 3 separate spark jobs or as a single job)?

Comment: I doubt it will have a significant difference using one method or the other. The operation on the RDD will trigger a job submission on its own and will get the resources available. Both methods are guaranteed to be sequential, so I don't see a significant difference. But you could try both and compare as it doesn't take much code changes to switch between one and the other.